# How to publish a script including triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've published a script with an "onFormSubmit" trigger to the gallery.

When users install the script the trigger is not installed and the users have to go through the process of adding the trigger themselves.
Am I doing something wrong or is this by purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior, copies don't have triggers copied with it but GAS provides full access to trigger creation.

You didn't mention was kind of script you where using but here is an example of a spreadsheet bound script that handles the install process in a quite userfriendly way with a menu that changes when the trigger is set or not providing an install routine that any user should be able to understand.

feel free to adapt to your use case.

```
function onOpen() {
  var installMenu = [ {name: "Install triggers", functionName: "setTrigger"}
                    ];
  var normalMenu = [ {name: "do something", functionName: "doIt"}
                    ];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if(!UserProperties.getProperty('triggers')){
    sheet.addMenu("Custom menu",installMenu);
  }else{
    sheet.addMenu("Custom menu",normalMenu);
  }
}

function setTrigger(){
  var trig = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet('0AnqSFd3iikE3dG5CQzdpV2tyMzRvdlY1RlVOUDc5RHc').onFormSubmit().create();
  UserProperties.setProperty('triggers',trig.getUniqueId());
  Browser.msgBox('Please refresh your Browser');
}

function onFormSubmit(){
  //do something
}

function doIt(){
  //
}
```